# "Come out with your hands up… and something with coconut"

Tags: meaning

English as a second language here. I'd like to ask why this quote from *The Simpsons* (from episode 9F20 "[Marge in Chains](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Marge_in_Chains/Quotes)") is funny and what it means.

> **Chief Wiggum** (to Marge, at the Kwik-E-Mart): All right, come out with your hands up, two cups of coffee, an auto freshener that says "Capricorn", and something with coconut on it.

Comment: I think the context is what will make it funny and I can guess what that probably is. Please could you explain the situation when this is said?

Comment: The short answer is that this is a play on the use of *with* to express manner (*come out with your hands up*, a police cliché from TV and movies) and accompaniment (*come out carrying the following list of items*). So there is humor in the syllepsis, and there is humor in the ridiculousness of the items to be brought out, and there is humor in the demand being made by the lazy, gluttonous Chief Wiggum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's topic is better covered as writing advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is more appropriate to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 11):

The expression *[Come out with your hands up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mn66WpxUrW0)* is a very serious command from a law enforcement officer:

[image]

The *[irony](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/irony)* of combining that serious command with the silly shopping list might strike a funny bone:

[image]

Comment: What a cute picture!

Comment: It's not so much that it is a silly shopping list, but rather that the cop is listing (silly) demands, rather than the criminal.

Comment: True in fact, @KitZ.Fox. This is one reason *The Simpsons* has been so broadly popular. The writers routinely embed multiple layers of irony in their scripts to catch us at every turn. It's a shame this question was closed so quickly. It could have been a **more** engaging open conversation, but I have been enjoying it regardless.

Answer (score 8):

It's a slight pun or play on words, because there are two meanings of 'with':

- Come out "with your hands up" means '**being** with your hands being up'
- Come out "with two cups of coffee" means '**possessing** two cups of coffee'

The contrast in tone should make it amusing or silly:

- With your hands up is very serious (you may be shot by police)
- With coffee is very every-day and friendly

"... and something with coconut on it" means '... and with candy or a donut or something', which is a joke about Chief Wiggum's perpetually wanting donuts:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the picture of Springfield Police Chief Wiggums eating something that surely has coconut on it! :-)

Comment: +1 For the added dimension of Chief Wiggums with coffee and donuts!

Comment: Great answer sir. It gave me a lot of clarity. hats off

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the first part, the sentence is an order issued by a police officer to a suspect or suspects.

It is humorous because the police officers are mixing a legitimate law enforcement command, "come out with your hands up", with inappropriate requests for general goods.  In effect, they are have the suspect shop for them while making an arrest.

Furthermore, the list of goods requested contains an absurdly specific item, the air freshener with a specific astrological sign, and an extremely vague item, the "something with coconut on it".

These juxtapositions are intended to be funny, and to a degree they succeed.

Comment: Also, it's impossible to carry all those items out while having your hands up. So they couldn't even comply with the order at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think the second part of the command, more than a shopping list, is a reference to a game called *[scavenger hunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scavenger_hunt)*. This makes it even funnier by virtue of contrast with the first part.

Comment: Interesting perspective.